# Random variables with arbitrary positive correlation but without arbitrary negative correlation. Then $Cor(X_i,X_j)<\frac{-1}{n-1}$ not possible

Tags: probability, statistics, measure-theory

Let $X_i \in L_2$ be a sequence of pairwise correlated random variables. The random variables can have arbitrary positive correlation but can't have arbitrary negative correlation.

> How can I show that for $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ and $\forall i,j \in \{1,\ldots,n\}, i\neq j$
>
> $$\mathrm{Cor}(X_i,X_j)<\frac{-1}{n-1}$$
> is **not** possible

Comment: Are you sure that your claim is correct ? What if $n = 2$, $X_1 = -X_2$ with variance equal to $1$ ?

Comment: @dallonsi, it is correct; note the strict inequality in the question, whereas your example has an equality.

Comment: yes Marcus, thanks. My mistake

Answer (score 4):

The idea is to realize that covariance matrices are positive semi-definite.  Define variables $Y_j = X_j/ \sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(X_j)}.$  Seeking a contradiction, suppose that the condition you mention holds, i.e. $$\operatorname{Cor}(X_i,X_j) = \operatorname{Cov}(Y_i,Y_j) < -\frac{1}{n-1}.$$

Let $\Sigma$ be the covariance matrix of $(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)$.  Then $\Sigma$ has $1$'s on the diagonal, and each off-diagonal entry is less than $-\frac{1}{n-1}$.  If we define $x = (1,1,\ldots,1)^T$, then we see that $x^T \Sigma x < 0$, which contradicts the fact that covariance matrices are positive semi-definite.